# Lightbox doesn't work on dynamically loaded images after visiting other pages

Tags: html, ajax, json, caching, lightbox

Here's what I'm trying to do:
I'm loading dynamically (with JSON and php) some images from my DB to my index.html page. When the image is clicked it opens in lightbox. I managed to achieve it. Now here's my problem - if I go to another page, return to index.html and click the image again - it doesn't work, the image is opened separately. How can I fix it?

Here are the relevant codes:

index.html:

```
$(function(){
    Shadowbox.init();
    $.getJSON("inc/API.php", {command:"top3"},
        function(result){
            for(var i = 0; i<result.length; i++)
                $("<a href='images/"+result[i].imageFileName
                    +"' rel='shadowbox' title='"+result[i].imageHeader+"'><img width='200' height='200' src='images/"+result[i].imageFileName+"' /></a>").appendTo("#top3");
         });
});
```

API.php (it will request a query string from BusinessLogic.php):

```
case "top3" :
    echo getTop3();
    break;
```

BusinessLogic.php:

```
function getTop3()
    {
        return json_encode(select("SELECT imageFileName, imageHeader, imageDescription FROM ranks JOIN images on images.imageID = ranks.imageID GROUP BY images.imageFileName ORDER BY AVG(rank) DESC LIMIT 3"));
    }
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind your lightbox javascript to the images after they're inserted into the DOM. I'm surprised it works the first time.

Try putting `Shadowbox.init()` inside the ajax callback, after the for loop.

```
$(function(){
    $.getJSON("inc/API.php", {command:"top3"}, function(result) {
        for(var i = 0; i<result.length; i++) {
            $("<a href='images/" + result[i].imageFileName + "' rel='shadowbox' title='" + result[i].imageHeader + "'><img width='200' height='200' src='images/" + result[i].imageFileName + "' /></a>").appendTo("#top3");
        }
        Shadowbox.init();
     });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I tried your suggestion and it sort of worked - after I visited another page and came back to index.html this lightbox worked only on the first image out of the 3 returned.

Comment: Oops! I wrote "after the for loop" but then my code put it in the for loop. I've corrected it.

Comment: Thank you so very much! That sure did the trick and now everything works just fine! Again, thank you!

Comment: Apparently, I don't have enough rep. to vote up your answer... :(